# Creating a pivot based on rules

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataset like:

```
+---------------+----+
| Grade         | ID |
+---------------+----+
| Copper        | 1  |
+---------------+----+
| Copper        | 2  |
+---------------+----+
| Copper Bonded | 2  |
+---------------+----+
| Fiber         | 3  |
+---------------+----+
| Fiber         | 4  |
+---------------+----+
```

I would like a result like this:

```
+----+--------+
| ID | Copper |
+----+--------+
| 1  | A      |
+----+--------+
| 2  | B      |
+----+--------+
| 3  | C      |
+----+--------+
| 4  | C      |
+----+--------+
```

The ruleset is something like this:

```
A :  Copper only
B :  Copper and Copper Bonded
C :  Fiber only
```

**Is this a candidate for a pivot, how do I express this as a sql query?**

Comment: I think you need `CASE`

Comment: @Sami it's kind of a complicated one, i'm not sure how to do an aggregate case

Comment: What would you want if there were an ID that had both Copper and Fiber?   Or more generally speaking, if none of the rules apply fully?

Comment: let's call it 'D'

Comment: It is a little ambiguous what you want here. Can you provide table structures, sample data and desired output? The "ruleset" is really vague.

Comment: when the ID is associated with copper only, then 'A', when the ID is associated with both copper and bonded copper then 'B', etc. please don't read too much into the rules, i am just lost on how to create these simple aggregation-type rules into a pivot

Comment: I can help you but there just isn't anything solid here to work with. It depends on what your data looks like. It could a simple case expression or something far more complicated.

Comment: Why for the TOP 2 rows you group them, and the 2 last rows are not grouping? weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a delimited trick and evaluated that:

```
create table #temp  (grade varchar(100),id int)
insert into #temp
values
('Copper',1)
,('Copper',2)
,('Copper bonded',2)
,('Fiber',3)
,('Fiber',4)

;with cte as
(
select distinct id,stuff((select '|' + grade
                from #temp
                where id = t1.id
                group by grade
                order by grade
                for xml path('')
                ),1,1,'') as Combined
from #temp t1
)

select id,
    case combined
        when 'Copper' then 'A'
        when 'Copper|Copper Bonded' then 'B'
        when 'Fiber' then 'C'
        else 'Unknown'
    end as Copper 
from cte



drop table #temp
```

Results:

```
id  Copper
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   C
```

Comment: this looks like the most reliable solution thank you so much!

Comment: If you have other groups just add them to the case statement. Remember that they are ordered alphabetically by grade.

Comment: to make it even faster i would create a table with your potential results and do a join and index the column that you are referencing.

Answer (score 2):

Ok you definitely need to use CASE, and it is complex, and you have only given us a "something like this" ruleset, so I will give you some psuedocode to point you in the direction of a solution, and your final code will be "something like this" depending on your actual rules:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
  CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT a row with this ID WHERE Grade='Copper')
      AND EXISTS(SELECT a row with this ID WHERE Grade='Copper Bonded')
      AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT a row with this ID WHERE Grade is something other than 'Copper' or 'Copper Bonded')
        THEN 'B'
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT a row with this ID WHERE Grade='Copper')
      AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT a row with this ID WHERE Grade is something other than 'Copper')
        THEN 'A'
    WHEN ... {by now you should be starting to get the idea}
  END AS Copper
FROM MyTable t1  --be sure to alias your table so you can correlate your EXISTS subqueries
```

Comment: when you say " a row with this ID " you mean the ID that we are selecting on the first line, right? the "DISTINCT ID" ??

Comment: Yes, so you will join your outer table (t1) to the table in the FROM clause of your sub-select on ID.

Answer (score 1):

Its really weird case and conditions but here is an idea:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
    GRADE VARCHAR(25)
    );
INSERT INTO T VALUES
('Copper'),
('Copper'),
('Copper Bonded'),
('Fiber'),
('Fiber');
with cte as (
SELECT ID, GRADE, row_number () over (partition by grade order by id) rn
FROM T
),
Final as (
select id, case when grade = 'Copper'and rn = 1 then 'A' 
                when grade= 'Copper Bonded' then 'B'
                when grade = 'Fiber' then 'C' end k
from cte)

select  row_number () over (order by k) id,k as Copper 
from final
where k is not null
```

Results:

```
+----+--------+
| id | Copper |
+----+--------+
|  1 | A      |
|  2 | B      |
|  3 | C      |
|  4 | C      |
+----+--------+
```

Comment: this is brilliant, is there a way to do this so that we do not use a table because i need to make this a view

Comment: he only made a table to hold your data

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' You can create your `VIEW` and use the `CTE` inside it.

Comment: am i correct in assuming that the order of the CASE statements here is essential? since for example, if we want to change the rules.. say that copper+titanium = Y and copper+bondedcopper (and nothing else for that ID then = Z

Comment: I use Order by K just to give you the ID as your expected results, you can change what you need.